# Remove group indicator just for a single group

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

[First Question]

Hi I have an expandable listview, and I was wondering if there is a way for me to remove the group indicator of the first group (groupPosition == 0) ? or in any group whatsoever.

All I've come across when researching were solutions to remove the indicator when the group is empty (ie. define a state_empty in the selector and set an image for it)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using DrawableRight for group indicators as opposed to using the ExpandableListView's groupindicator.